# Export User Info to CSV from Front End

Tags: php, shortcode, database, export, csv

Trying to export to CSV from WordPress front end. Here is what I have so far. I was able to export to CSV from the admin area, but for some reason I am unable to export from the front end. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Add action hook only if action=download_csv_sl
if ( isset($_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'download_csv_sl' )  {
// Handle CSV Export
add_action( 'init', 'csv_export_sl');
}

function csv_export_sl() {
    // Check if we are in WP-Admin
    if( is_admin() ){ return false; }

    // Nonce Check
    $nonce = isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) ? $_GET['_wpnonce'] : '';
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'download_csv_sl' ) ) {
        die( 'Security check error' );
    }

    // Get Current Date and Time
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $currentDate = date('Y_m_d-H_i_s');

    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $filename = 'Store_List-' . $currentDate . '.csv';

    // Get Quarter and Ranking from Shop Profiles
    $getQuarter = do_shortcode('[usermeta key="current_quarter" user="717"]');
    if ($getQuarter == '1'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1';
    } elseif ($getQuarter == '2'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1_89';
    } elseif ($getQuarter == '3'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1_90';
    } elseif ($getQuarter == '4'){
        $currentQuarter = 'ranker_q1_91';
    } else {
        $currentQuarter = '';
    }

    // Name the columns in the spreadsheet
    $header_row = array(
        'Store Number',
        'Address',
        'Franchisee',
        'Q'.$getQuarter.' Ranking'
    );
    $data_rows = array();

    // Query users
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'role__in'    => ['shop','shop_co','shop_noco'],
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ) );   
    $users = $user_query->get_results();

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        if (!empty($user->Group)){
            $row = array(
                $user->Store_Number,             // Get Store Number
                $user->Address,                  // Get Address
                $user->display_name,             // Get Franchisee
                $user->$currentQuarter          // Get Ranking
            );
            $data_rows[] = $row;
        }
    }

    $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
    fprintf( $fh, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8' );
    header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}" );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Pragma: public' );
    fputcsv( $fh, $header_row );
    foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
        fputcsv( $fh, $data_row );
    }
    fclose( $fh );

    ob_end_flush();

    die();
}

add_shortcode('bc_export', 'csv_export_storelist_shortcode');
function csv_export_storelist_shortcode() {
    $url = $_GET['uri'];
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'download_csv_sl' );
    $exportList = '<a href="'. $url . '&action=download_csv_sl&_wpnonce='. $nonce .'" class="page-title-action">Export to CSV</a>';
    return $exportList;
}
```

It seems the issue lies in the `$url` link path inside the shortcode, but I can't figure out what the path is. The current code results in a Page Not Found when clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured out a way to make it work. I just removed the need for a url altogether. Here's what I did in case anybody else wants to know.

I changed the link to an form input button:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="bc_export" class="btn btn-export" value="Export Store List for '.$atts['value'].'" />
</form>
```

And changed the `$_GET['action']` to a `$_POST[]`:

```
if ( isset($_POST["bc_export"])) {
    add_action( 'init', 'bc_export_function');
}
```